# Which one is effective- filtering by narrowing or direct filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, rdbms

Which one of the below two will be faster, provided that invoice.userId and invoiceline.invoiceId both have indexes on it. invoice.id is a primarykey so even that has an index.

```
select invoiceline.item, invoiceline.rate, invoiceline.vat
from invoice 
inner join invoiceline
  on invoice.id = invoiceline.invoiceId
where invoiceline.id = @invoiceId
AND invoice.userId = @userId
```

```
select invoiceline.item, invoiceline.rate, invoiceline.vat
from invoiceline
where invoiceline.invoiceId = @invoiceId
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand performance, then you should try running the queries on your data on your system.
In this case, both will run quite quickly.  But the first version has to look up data in two pages (or two indexes) and the second only has to access one table.  I would expect the second to be marginally faster.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I was thinking that I've less records in `invoice` to filter by `userId` than in `invoiceline` to filter by `invoiceId`. Hence asked it.